# boost regex exception thrown from constructor for .*{

Tags: c++, regex, boost

Boost version 1.60.0
gcc 4.8.4

When I construct a boost::regex object with the string:  `.*{`   I get an exception stating that:

```
what():  Missing } in quantified repetition.  The error occurred while parsing the regular expresion: '.*{>>>HERE>>>'.
```

This error occurs when the object is a `boost::regex::extended` type, but not if it is `boost::regex::perl`.

So the following throws the exception:

```
regString(".*{");
boost::regex reg_e(regString, boost::regex::extended);
```

but this does not:

```
regString(".*{");
boost::regex reg_p(regString, boost::regex::perl);
```

Is this expected behavior or a bug?
If it is expected, why?  and what is an appropriate work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{` is a special character **in this context**, you need to escape it.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html

> Note that the "{" and "}" characters will treated as ordinary literals
>   when used in a context that is not a repeat: this matches Perl 5.x
>   behavior. For example in the expressions "ab{1", "ab1}" and "a{b}c"
>   the curly brackets are all treated as literals and no error will be
>   raised.

Comment: Ah, I see how this works.  For completeness, I get the same error for a `boost::regex::basic` type even when the regex string is `.*\{`

Comment: Yes, it works. I was creating regex objects for all 3 types (basic, extended, Perl-compatible), so one would fail when another worked. I am now try/catching each object construction separately and reporting to the user when one fails, while allowing the others to continue.  Thanks!